# How to target each child element when their parent is clicked in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to achieve an effect on one "li" element every time I click on '.parent'. but it keeps working on all li elements at once.
what I want is when I trigger click event on .parent the first li should be highlighted, then second time i trigger the click on ,parent second li highlighted and so on
HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.parent').on('click', function(){
  $('li').addclass('true');
});
```

Comment: each = every. What do want to achieve? Explain it without using the word 'each' and 'every'

Comment: I want to achieve css() change on one 'li'  everytime I click on '.parent'.

Comment: Which one of the "li"?

Comment: all of them, but only a one every time I trigger the click event on the parent.

Comment: I mean when I trigger click event on .parent   the first li should be highlighted, then second time i trigger the click on ,parent second li highlighted and so on,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT for the completely different question:

```js
$('.parent').on('click', function(evt) {
  $(evt.target).find('li:not(.true)').first().addClass('true');
});
```

```css
.true {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it to work on each "li" element every time I click on .parent

Comment: since I use $(.target) the function stop working. and I want to target all the li elements but only one every time the click event is triggered on parent.

Comment: I never wrote `$(.target)`. And since my example is executable, you can directly verify that the code does exactly what you say it should.

Comment: I meant at both cases of this.target or evt.target.  I appreciate your tries to help, I want to treat those li elements as an array when .parent is clicked first li got da effect, another click on .parent sec 'li' should get the effect and so on till all 'li' elements get the effect.

Comment: ...and they do. Click on "Run code snippet", see *1, *2, *3; click on the bullets (the only place that registers the click on `ul`), and see exactly that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

styles-sheet

```
<style>
   .true{color:red;border:1px solid red;}
</style>
```

jquery code

```
$(document).on('click','.parent',function(){
   $(this).find('ul li').addClass('true');
});
```

or you can add css dynamically using css function of jquery like below

```
$(document).on('click','.parent',function(){
   $(this).find('ul li').css({'color':'red','border':'1px solid red'});
});
```